# Python redirect (with delay)

Tags: python, redirect, flask

So I have this python page running on flask. It works fine until I want to have a redirect.

```
@app.route("/last_visit")
def check_last_watered():
    templateData = template(text = water.get_last_watered())
    return render_template('main.html', **templateData)
    return redirect(url_for('new_page')) #with a delay here of 3 secs
```

The site works fine, but does not redirect and I wouldn't know how to delay the whole thing. 
Ideas... Please :-)

Comment: Use `sleep()` might help.

Comment: You can't return twice from a function and can't tell a browser to render a page then redirect. Either return a page which redirects using Javascript or return an HTTP redirect. (You should probably understand what the `redirect` method actually does)

Comment: ok, well ... after two seconds the page should forward to another page.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to render a template and redirect after three seconds you can pass `refresh` as time and `url` with the URL you need to redirect.

```
@app.route('/error/', methods=['GET'])
def error():
    return render_template('error.html'), {"Refresh": "1; url=https://google.com"}
```

Comment: Oh, that's a nice one! Thanks, @Adrián

Comment: this is much more better than putting stupid setTimeout in javascript

Answer (score 5):

Well, your function just returns a rendered template and never reaches the redirect statement. If you want to show a page AND then do a redirect after a delay, use a javascript redirect in your template:

```
@app.route("/last_visit")
def check_last_watered():
    templateData = template(text = water.get_last_watered())
    templateData['redirect_url'] = url_for('new_page')
    return render_template('main.html', **templateData)
```

Then in your `main.html`:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = '{{redirect_url}}';
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** Also, have a look at an alternative (and possibly better) way by Adrián, where you can return a `Refresh` header along with your rendered template response.

Comment: Thanks. So I am trying this:

@app.route("/last_visit")
def check_last_watered():
    templateData = template(text = water.get_last_watered())
    return render_template('main.html', **templateData['main.html'] = url_for('new_page'))

with the javascript in the main.html

but flask crashes

Comment: @SabrinaTesla I have updated my answer to include your flask view in its entirety

Comment: Thank you. the site is now reloading every 2000ms in every case, not just for @app.route("/last_visit")

Comment: I am also getting this error: BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'new_page'.

Comment: Please read up on flask a little. A good point to start is the quickstart guide: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `return` statement and return a string format.

As the `<redirect url>` you could set any URL from available to your back-end.

This solution is similar to dmitrybelyakov's, but it's a quick fix without having to deal with new, small html templates.

```
return f"<html><body><p>You will be redirected in 3 seconds</p><script>var timer = setTimeout(function() {{window.location='{ <redirect url> }'}}, 3000);</script></body></html>"
```

Example:

Lets say you want to submit a form and have a run time issue that requires you to do this redirect after a certain time.

```
@app.route('/')
def your_func():
  form = FormFunc()

  if form.validate_on_submit():
    # do something
    wait_time = 3000
    seconds = wait_time / 1000
    redirect_url = 'https://www.example.com/'

    # if the validation is successful, forward to redirect page, wait 3 seconds, redirect to specified url
    return f"<html><body><p>You will be redirected in { seconds } seconds</p><script>var timer = setTimeout(function() {{window.location='{ redirect url }'}}, { wait_time });</script></body></html>"

# if the validation is not successful, reload the form
return render_template('formPage.html', form=form)
```