# Flask redirect any other route to a page

Tags: python, flask

I currently have an app that uses flask like so:

```py
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=dashboard.render)
app.add_url_rule('/callback', view_func=bot.callback, methods=['POST'])
```

Basically, `dashboard.render` will display a webpage while `bot.callback` is a special url for a bot that I made.

If a user access `/` then then it would trigger `dashboard.render`, while if he/she accesses `/callback` with a `POST` method, then it would trigger `bot.callback`. However, try to access any other site, for example `/123` or `/asd` then it would trigger a `404 Not Found`.

Is there any way to let users that access unavailable urls (in my case, other than `/` and `/callback`) to trigger `dashboard.render`? Also, as `/callback` is only available through `POST`, can I also redirect `405 Method not allowed` errors to just display a webpage using `dashboard.render`?

Oh and if perhaps this is insecure or not a good thing to do, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870188/does-flask-support-regular-expressions-in-its-url-routing

Comment: Already answered, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678397/python-flask-default-route-possible

Answer (score 0):

i think it's **not user friendly** to redirect users accessing `404 Not Found` or `405 method not allowed` pages  (by error or even exploiting your site) without warning or some useful messages.

for your case you need `redirect` function in `errorhandler` like so

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def handle_bad_request(e):
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

@app.errorhandler(405)
def handle_methodnotallowed_request(e):
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
```

a better approach would be redirecting users after delay (5 sec for e.g) so users don't get lost and don't think your app has bugs or even bad they never trust you as they may think your app is suspicious, have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53320037/python-redirect-with-delay)